# Filter Vuex state array of object returns empty array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have state which receives data from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/`. I want to filter the data based on the status `completed:true` or `completed:false`.

And I have the following method to filter the filter the array:

```js
filterByStatus(status) {
  const filteredResults = this.allTodos.filter(todo => todo.completed == status)
  console.log(filteredResults)
}
```

Here, I receive `true` or `false` as parameter for the method. But `console.log(filteredResults)` returns an empty array.

```js
filterByStatus(status) {
  let filteredResults = [];
  this.allTodos.map(item => {
    if (item.completed == status) {
      filteredResults.push(item);
    }
  });
  console.log(filteredResults);
}
```

I have also tried the map method  but the result is same an empty array.

I had `console.log(this.allTodos)` the result is:

```
 [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, __ob__: Observer]
```

Is this the cause of Observer ??

Comment: Are you sure your function receives a boolean? Cause if for some reason your parameter is a string, `"true" == true` will return false, and there will be no item in your array.

Comment: Yes, i'm getting `true` and `false` on console.log without quotes

Comment: My bad I was receiving string in status. Changed code to `const newList = this.allTodos.filter(todo => todo.completed == JSON.parse(status)); ` now it works

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: @palaѕн I already solved it with the changes I've mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here you should use map:

```
        this.allTodos.map(item => {
          if (item.completed == status) {
             filteredResults.push(item);
          }
        });
```

but instead a forEach

```
        this.allTodos.forEach(item => {
          if (item.completed == status) {
             filteredResults.push(item);
          }
        });
```